# BrainTree PayPal configuration doesn't work with dropin integration

Tags: paypal, braintree

I am trying to customize the "PayPal" button within the BrainTree dropin, ideally simply to move it somewhere else.

If I use the dropin integration, nothing happens - the usual blue button is rendered above the fields. When I choose custom, it works.  The BrainTree docs suggest that it should work in both setups.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<form id="paymentForm" action="/braintree.php" method="POST">
    <div id="hostedFields"></div>
    <input id="formSubmit" type="submit" value="Pay" />
    <div id="paypalContainer"</div>
</form>
```

And the javascript:

```
braintree.setup("<?=$clientToken ?>",
    "dropin",
    {
        container: "hostedFields",
        onPaymentMethodReceived: onNonce,
        onReady: onFormReady,
        onError: onError,
        paypal:
        {
            container: "paypalContainer",
            singleUse: true,
            amount: PRODUCT_PRICE,
            currency: PRODUCT_CURRENCY,
        }
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got a reply from Support; it looks like it really isn't possible to specify the location of the PayPal button with dropin setup.